# Selenium WebDriver using TestNG and Excel

Tags: java, excel, selenium, webdriver, testng

Hello i really need help with Selenium WebDriver using TestNG and Excel

i try to get data from excel to open browser and navigate URL. its work successfully and terminal and testng report showing test pass but its not open browser or doing anything its just run its self and show report

**Config File**

```
public void openBrowser(String browser){
        try {
            if (browser.equals("Mozilla")) {
                driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            } else if(browser.equals("IE")){
                driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
            } else if(browser.equals("Chrome")){
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "\\Applications\\Google Chrome.app\\Contents\\MacOS\\Google Chrome ");
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }


    public void navigate(String baseUrl){
        try {
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
            driver.navigate().to(baseUrl);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
```

**And Test Execute File**

```
public class NewTest {
    public String exPath = Config.filePath;
    public String exName = Config.fileName;
    public String exWrSheet = "Logiin Functional Test";
    public Config config;

    @BeforeTest
    public void openBrowser() {
        config = new Config();
        Excel.setExcelFile(exPath+exName, exWrSheet);
        String browser = Excel.getCellData(1, 2);
        config.openBrowser(browser);
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void navigate() {
        config = new Config();
        Excel.setExcelFile(exPath+exName, exWrSheet);
        String baseUrl = Excel.getCellData(2, 2);
        config.navigate(baseUrl);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("Test");
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void closeBroser() {
        //Config.tearDown();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have quite enough rep to make a comment, which I would prefer here, but if you aren't getting any sort of exception, I'd suspect the value you're getting for the **browser** variable is not matching anything in your if-then-else in openBrowser and then falling through.  Step through the code with a debugger or just add:

```
String browser = Excel.getCellData(1, 2);
System.out.println("Browser value from Excel =" + browser);
config.openBrowser(browser);
```

to see what you're reading from the file.

Comment: Adding a last else and throwing an exception there may help to debug

Comment: Very strange. I've taken this code and put it into Eclipse, removing the Excel read and just putting hard coding the browser name, and it opens up all the browsers fine for me.         
  
It's strange because it isn't even getting to your @Test and running it.  What does it say on the TestNG results tab?  Also, can you share a screenshot of your testng-customsuite.xml?
  
I'm not sure if the navigate method will work because you're instantiating a new config and trying to use **driver** when it hasn't been set to anything. But first figure out why the browsers won't open.

Comment: Ok the open browser its work now but only Mozila, rest of not open and TestNG not giving any error its keep passing.. anyway what I really want to do is i try to make Page Object Model framework like (MVC Type) but I want all the data coming from my TestCase which I use excel file and run it. Also I want Write the excel after exciting the test  result(Pass/fail) and Actual Result. If you have any idea or any link that will help me to built a Selenium MVC  framework. Here is one of sample MVC framework the I made 
https://github.com/saif0909/Selenium-MVC-Framework
Thanks for help.

Comment: Nguyen raises a good point, but I am assuming your config has some **WebDriver driver=null;** line T above what you've pasted, especially if it's woking in Firefox.  If it is just IE and Chrome left, you probably don't have the external drivers set up.  See: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver and https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver.

Comment: As for your MVC question, that's really outside the scope of this question, but there are plenty of resources online (ex. http://seleniummaster.com/sitecontent/index.php/selenium-test-automation-with-java/25-how-selenium-model-view-controller-test-framework-works).

Answer (score 0):

1 - TestNg is always pass because you are using "void" method and you catch "all" exception

2 - No browser opened because in openBrowser(String browser), NullPointException throws and you already catch it.

-> you need to init an instance of WebDriver and pass it through your test.